# How can I parse a string and split it into two parts at a special character with javascript?

Tags: javascript, split

How can I take a string and split it at a special character into two new variables (and remove the special chars) with javascript?

For example take:

```
var X = Peggy Sue - Teacher
```

and turn it into:

```
varnew1 = Peggy Sue

varnew2 = Teacher
```

I guess it should also include a condition... if the string has a "-" then do this.

Comment: with String.split? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp - is the first result in Google search on "javascript string split"

Comment: Winchestro  - well played

Comment: @Igor "First" does not imply "Appropriate".

Comment: For this case you can use a split regex like `.split(/\s*-\s*/)`, such that the surrounding whitespace, if any, is removed. (Split always uses a regular expression, first converting strings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split` is probably what you want. Here is a very simple example

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/59Lft5qn/)

```
var string = 'Peggy Sue - Teacher'

var new1 = string.split('-')[0].trim();
var new2 = string.split('-')[1].trim();

console.log(new1); // "Peggy Sue"
console.log(new2); // "Teacher"
```

And if you want to place a simple condition on it looking for `-` you can do so with the following

```
var string = 'Peggy Sue - Teacher'

var new1 =  string.indexOf('-') !== -1 ? string.split('-')[0].trim() : string
var new2 = string.indexOf('-') !== -1 ? string.split('-')[1].trim() : string
```

### [Second Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh1n2gwy/)

Comment: Nice work. Thank you sir!

Comment: If you found this helpful please consider accepting the answer so we can both gain a little rep @user3577331

Answer (score 0):

var result = str.split("-");

will give you an array with 2 members,

result[0] = Peggy Sue
result[1] = Teacher